# How to make a smooth curve in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, path

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to make the connection between a straight line and the curved one smoother so it will not be visible to the eye, this is my code:

```
struct CustomShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        // Set the desired number of segments
        let numberOfSegments = 5

        // Calculate the width of each segment to fit the rect width
        let segmentWidth = rect.width / CGFloat(numberOfSegments - 1)

        // Adjust the start point to be centered
        let startY = rect.midY // Start in the middle of the rect
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: startY))

        // Draw the segments
        for i in 0..<numberOfSegments {
            let xOffset = CGFloat(i) * segmentWidth
            var yPoint = (i % 2 == 0) ? rect.minY : rect.maxY
            
            if i == numberOfSegments - 1 {
                yPoint = rect.midY
            }
            
            let nextPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + xOffset, y: yPoint)
            
            // Add line to the next point
            path.addLine(to: nextPoint)

            // Prepare for curve
            if i < numberOfSegments - 1 {
                let curveControlPointYOffset: CGFloat = 50 // Smaller value for a subtle transition
                let controlPointY = (i % 2 == 0) ? yPoint - curveControlPointYOffset : yPoint + curveControlPointYOffset
                
                // Control point is now adjusted to make the curve start smoothly from the line
                let controlPointX = rect.minX + xOffset + segmentWidth / 2
                let controlPoint = CGPoint(x: controlPointX, y: controlPointY)
                
                // Curve to the right point
                let rightPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + xOffset + segmentWidth, y: yPoint)
                path.addQuadCurve(to: rightPoint, control: controlPoint)
            }
        }

        return path
    }
}
```

This is how I would like it to look like:
[image]

Comment: The curves you want looks like circular arcs, not quad curves. Use [`addArc`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/addarc(center:radius:startangle:endangle:clockwise:transform:)) to draw them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should draw *circular* arcs, not quad curves. The two sides of a circle is tangent to the vertical lines you are drawing here, so if you just draw an arc from 0 to 180 degrees with the diameter of `segmentWidth`, it would look smooth.

```
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var path = Path()
    let numberOfSegments = 5
    
    let segmentWidth = rect.width / CGFloat(numberOfSegments - 1)
    let radius = segmentWidth / 2

    let startY = rect.midY
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: startY))

    // Draw the segments
    for i in 0..<numberOfSegments {
        let xOffset = CGFloat(i) * segmentWidth
        // you should subtract radius from the min/max Ys
        // otherwise you'd be drawing outside the bounds of the rect
        var yPoint = (i % 2 == 0) ? 
                    rect.minY + radius :
                    rect.maxY - radius
        
        if i == numberOfSegments - 1 {
            yPoint = rect.midY
        }
        
        let nextPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + xOffset, y: yPoint)
        path.addLine(to: nextPoint)

        if i < numberOfSegments - 1 {
            let tangent1End = CGPoint(
                x: nextPoint.x + radius,
                y: 100000 * (i % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1)
            )
            let tangent2End = CGPoint(x: nextPoint.x + segmentWidth, y: nextPoint.y)
            path.addArc(tangent1End: tangent1End, tangent2End: tangent2End, radius: radius)
        }
    }
    return path
}
```

Here I'm using the [`addArc`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/addarc(tangent1end:tangent2end:radius:transform:)) overload that uses two tangents, with the tangents' intersection point having a very large (in magnitude) y position, in order to draw a semicircle. I could have also used [the other overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/addarc(center:radius:startangle:endangle:clockwise:transform:)) that takes the centre and start/end angles, but using that creates separate subpaths, which might be undesirable.

Usage:

```
CustomShape()
    .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 16)
    .stroke(.white, style: .init(lineWidth: 5, dash: [10]))
    .padding()
    .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
```

Example output:

[image]

Side note: if you are planning on drawing the whole thing in your "desired result" image, with all the numbers, the arrow at the beginning and the red circles at the end, you should consider using a `Canvas` instead of a `Shape`.

Comment: How can i now place an image at 75% of the path length?

Comment: @kobiBrooks Use a `Canvas`, and draw the parts of the path until the image, draw the image, and then draw the rest of the path. Post a new question if you are stuck.

Comment: Ok, and how do i know it's 75%?

Comment: @kobiBrooks Do some maths. Your path only consists of straight lines and arcs, all of their lengths can be calculated.